# Can anyone explain the behavior and the difference among "onBind", "preparedFromRequest", "onReveal", "onReset" in GWTP?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Ok, I am very confused about "onBind", "preparedFromRequest", "onReveal", "onReset" in GWTP. I don't know When & in Which circumstance these methods were called.

Ok, i got `Page1Presenter.java` (tokenName: `page1`) has the following codes:

```
@Override
protected void onBind(){
    System.out.println("on bind");
}

@Override
protected void prepareFromRequest(PlaceRequest request){
    System.out.println("prepared from request");
}

@Override
protected void onReveal(){
    System.out.println("on reveal");
}

@Override
protected void onReset(){
    System.out.println("on reset");
}
```

Now, i open page1 in browser, url: `abc.com/#page1;param=1`, then it prints out:

```
on bind
prepared from request
on reveal
on reset
```

Then, I go to `abc.com/#page2` & then press back button, now it prints out:

```
prepared from request
on reset
```

Then, change param & enter `abc.com/#page1;param=2`, it will show:

```
prepared from request
on reset
```

Then, i click other browser tab & click back to the tab containing the url `abc.com/#page1;param=2`, then nothing happened. I expect `onReveal` will be called.

Also, `System.out.println();` is too simple so we can't see the difference between `preparedFromRequest` & `onReset`.

If we have a lot of complicated code & if we put that code in `preparedFromRequest`, will it behave differently if putting into `onReset`?

& Do they behave the same in different browsers?

Answer (score 1):

[This short description on GWTP Presenter Lifecycle](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Presenter-Lifecycle) answers most part of your question.

[image: GWTP Lifecycle]

Comment: p is visible. When & in Which situation p is visible? like u minimize browser?